# Is the たん in this phrase the same as たく or たい?

Tags: meaning

そんなことを言って. またいつもみたいに千春から抱きついたんでしょう?

So 千春 is a name (Chiharu) and the one who says this phrase is 千春 herself.
What does the たん mean here ?

From what I can translate it means

You’re saying stuff like that but you actually want me to embrace you like always right ?

Is たん the same as たく or たい  (which meanig “to want” to do something)

In anime you often hear the phrase

死にたくない (I don’t want to die)

Or

知りたい (I want to know)

So is たん some kind of slang thing ?

Also can the  たん, たく , たい  only be used after the MASU stem of a verb ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ん is a contraction of の.

抱きついたんでしょう?
抱きついたのでしょう?

This の is related to のだ.
According to "A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar", page 325:
のだ: a sentence ending which indicates that the speaker is explaining or asking for an explanation about some information shared with the hearer, or is talking about something emotively, as if it were of common interest to the speaker and the hearer.

Also can the たん, たく , たい only be used after the MASU stem of a verb?
たん no, but たく and  たい, yes.